# Routing Error when trying devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using devise to connect twitter and facebook, and i have two problem :
when i runn my app:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/10/finish_signup
```

i have first problem:

```
LoadError in UserController#finish_signup
Expected ../app/controllers/user_controller.rb to define UserController
```

When i reload this link, i have second problem:

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant UserController
```

Here, my routes:

```
Thuchanh::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks' }
  match '/users/:id/finish_signup', :to => 'user#finish_signup', via: [:get, :patch], :as => :finish_signup

  get "user/new"
  get "user/finish_signup"

  root :to => "welcome#index"
  get '/users/:id', :to => 'welcome#sucess', :as => "user" 
  resources :users
```

My user_controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        sign_in(@user == current_user ? @user : current_user, :bypass => true)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Your profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def finish_signup
    # authorize! :update, @user 
    if request.patch? && params[:user] #&& params[:user][:email]
      if @user.update(user_params)
        @user.skip_reconfirmation!
        sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
        redirect_to @user, notice: 'Your profile was successfully updated.'
      else
        @show_errors = true
      end
    end
...
```

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.19'
...

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0.2'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

My user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  TEMP_EMAIL_PREFIX = 'change@me'
  TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX = /\Achange@me/
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable
  validates_format_of :email, :without => TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX, on: :update

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  attr_accessible :pass, :username, :image, :age

  validates :username, :pass, :presence => true
  validates :username, :pass, :length => { :minimum => 4 }
  validates :username, :uniqueness => true
  def self.login(username,pass)
    user = find_by_username(username) and user = find_by_pass(pass)
    if user.nil?
      return nil
    else
    return user
    end
  end

  def unfollow(other_user)
    following_relations.find_by_following_id(other_user.id).destroy
  end

  def self.search(search)
    search_condition = "%" + search + "%"
    find(:all, :conditions => ['username LIKE ? OR age LIKE ?', search_condition, search_condition])
  end

  def self.find_for_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource = nil)

    identity = Identity.find_for_oauth(auth)
    user = signed_in_resource ? signed_in_resource : identity.user

    if user.nil?

      email_is_verified = auth.info.email && (auth.info.verified || auth.info.verified_email)
      email = auth.info.email if email_is_verified
      user = User.where(:email => email).first if email

      if user.nil?
        user = User.new(
          name: auth.extra.raw_info.name,

          email: email ? email : "#{TEMP_EMAIL_PREFIX}-#{auth.uid}-#{auth.provider}.com",
          password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        )
        user.skip_confirmation!
        user.save!
      end
    end


    if identity.user != user
      identity.user = user
      identity.save!
    end
    user
  end

  def email_verified?
    self.email && self.email !~ TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX
  end
end
```

Please! help me to fix that or tell me what problem of my code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check where your `UsersController` file is, put in expected place. And controller is in plural form (both file name and class name), you may have typos somewhere.

Comment: Yeah!! I used the different name User in controller, i'm so silly :))Thanks you